# Выпадающий список из Базы данных

Tags: java, android

Есть схожые темы, но не могу победить.

Есть бд firebird, с нее с помощью jdbc выбираю данные.
Данные из бд помещаю переробором в arraylist, а уже массив помещаю в адаптер, а адаптер в spinner.
Тут нет проблем.

Но мне нужно потом из выпадающего списка в бд найти значение, которое выбранное, а кто ж ищет значения по строке?!:)

Вот и вопрос, как правильно организовать выпадающий список, что бы пользователь выбрал из этого списка значения, а я без проблем это значение мог идентифицировать в бд?!

Нашел [интересное](http://droidtips.ru/zapolnenie-spinner-iz-bazy-dannykh-cherez-cursor-loader/) но видать древняя статья и не могу победить.

Comment: Вам надо не массив строк (если у вас так) в адаптере юзать, но массив моделей данных, которые содержат как заголовки, отображаемые в спиннере, так и ID записи в БД и всё остальное. Так у вас всегда будет под рукой ID

Comment: да, понимаю, есть примеры?

Comment: Например: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8116756/3212712

Comment: пробую, спасибо

Comment: Правильно понимаю, добавил класс с одним методом, выборкой в из запроса заполняю этот класс, а далее этот класс отправляю в адаптер

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, (List<String>) usr);

в результате приложение автоматически закрывается

Comment: Ошибка приведения типов. Тип в адаптере должен быть вашим созданным типом

Comment: ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, (List<usr>));

подчеркивает usr

Comment: `ArrayAdapter<ТУТ_ИМЯ_ВАШЕГО_КЛАССА_КОТОРЫЙ_ВЫ_СОЗДАЛИ_ДЛЯ_ХРАНЕНИЯ_ДАННЫХ_ПОЛУЧЕННЫХ_ИЗ_БД> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<ТУТ_ИМЯ_ВАШЕГО_КЛАССА_КОТОРЫЙ_ВЫ_СОЗДАЛИ_ДЛЯ_ХРАНЕНИЯ_ДАННЫХ_ПОЛУЧЕННЫХ_ИЗ_БД>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, usr));`

Comment: добавил три значения, появились http://prntscr.com/fdtoeg а где же значения?

Comment: Переопределите `toString()` метод в вашем классе-модели

Comment: что нужно сделать?

Comment: дошло

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }

Comment: спасибо, работает