# Как присвоить в Spinner каждой строке из списка отдельное значение?

Tags: android

У Москвы будет `url = "http///...."`, у Краснодара другое. По клику значения помещаются в `.setDataSource`, и запускается плеер.

```
play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        try {
            Player.setDataSource(spinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
            Player.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        stop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        play.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Player.start();
    }
});
```

[image: картинка]

Comment: Используйте не строки, но объекты для адаптера спиннера

Comment: Вот тут в комментах вся нужная инфа https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/672767/17609

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я делал радио. Использовал не спинер, а список и уже под списком использовал `chaild`, там скрывал ссылку на соединение, при выборе списка, передавалась ссылка на активити с проигрывателем. Если будет желание, то могу помочь в создании приложения.

Инициализация и присвоение значений:

```
 //Инициализируем элемент Spinner:
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

    //Настраиваем слушатель нажатий Spinner(Click Listener в смысле):
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);


    //Создаем массив элементов выпадающего списка:
    List<String> elements = new ArrayList<String>();

    elements.add("Прочее ссылка");
    elements.add("Ляляля");


    //Создаем для spinner адаптер:
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, elements);

    //Настраиваем внешний вид выпадающего списка, используя готовый системный шаблон:
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    //Присоединяем адаптер данных к spinner:
    spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

Прячем под элемент:

```
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    //Выбираем элемент выпадающего списка:
    String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
    //Показываем выбранный элемент с помощью Toast сообщения:
    Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Выбрано: " + item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    if(position == 0){
        codevizova.setText("ссылка 1");
    }
    if(position == 1){
        codevizova.setText("ссылка 2");
    }


public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```